# Login failed in php

Tags: php, mysql

Im a beginner in php and what i am trying to do is create a registration and login. I try to register a user and it works , but when i login is says :Login failed. I cant understand what is going on. Please somebody explain me what i have done wrong!

regproc.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['reg']))
{
require "dbconn.php";
//$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
//$password=md5(strip_tags($_POST['password']));

// $repass=md5(strip_tags($_POST['repassword']));

$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
// A higher "cost" is more secure but consumes more processing power
$cost = 10;

// Create a random salt
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');

// Prefix information about the hash so PHP knows how to verify it later.
// '$2a$?' Means we're using the Blowfish algorithm. The following two digits are the cost parameter.
$salt = sprintf('$2a$%02d$?', $cost) . $salt;

// Value:
// $2a$10$eImiTXuWVxfM37uY4JANjQ==

// Hash the password with the salt
$hash = crypt($password, $salt);

// Value:
// $2a$10$eImiTXuWVxfM37uY4JANjOL.oTxqp7WylW7FCzx2Lc7VLmdJIddZq

//if(!strcmp($password,$repass)==0)
//
//header('Location:./reg.php?pass=password not match');
//exit (0);
//
/*This insert command for username and password only, if you need any other column you can insert it here*/
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username,password,hash,email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$hash','$email')") or  die("".mysql_error());
//Here you can write conformation or success message or use any redirect

}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<label>Username:<input type="text" name="username" /></label>
<label>Password:<input type="password" name="password" /></label>
<label>Email:<input type="text" name="email" /></label>
<span style="size:10%;color:#FF0000"><?php if(isset($_GET["pass"])) { echo $_GET["pass"]; }
?></span>
<input type="submit" value="reg" name="reg" />

</form>
```

login.php

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username']; // e.g. 'Admin'
    $password = $_POST['password']; // e.g. 'gf45_gdf#4hg'; 

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=universiteti', 'root', '');
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT hash FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1');    
    $sth->bindParam(':username', $username);    
    $sth->execute();    
    $user = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    // Hashing the password with its hash as the salt returns the same hash
    if ( crypt($password, $user->hash) == $user->hash ) {      
      exit('Logged in successfully');
    }
    else
    {
        exit('Login failed');
    }
}    
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">    
    <input type='text' name="username"  maxlength="50" placeholder="Username" />    
    <input type='password' name='password' maxlength="50" />
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Log In' />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show us a var_dump() or print_r() of the user object of when the login failed ?

Comment: sorry for my stupid question but what to put inside var_dump() ?

Comment: var_dump($user); (Before the exit())

Comment: object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["hash"]=> string(2) "*0" }

Comment: There is nothing...
So the problem may come from your sql query.

Are you sure to select the right login ?
Edit : no, wait, is the hash really *0 ??

Comment: 21 koko 1234567    koko@gmail.com 0 *0

Comment: where 21-->id koko-->username 1234567-->password email and hash is *0  why is *0 ?

Comment: I can't see why it doesn't work.
Maybe you could try hash function, http://fr2.php.net/manual/fr/function.hash.php, 
Easier to use

Comment: but somebody else said to me that md5 is not the right thing to do..i am really stuck in this :(

Comment: what should be a hash (when create a column named hash in table in database) varchar,int? what else to put? because this may be the problem i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wrote this code for login. hope it will help you.

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","***");
if(!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("databasename", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT uname, upasswd FROM Users");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
if($row['uname'] == $username && $row['upasswd'] == $password) {

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
 }
}
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(\'Wrong username or password\')</script>';
}
?>
```

For Registration

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con) {
die('couldn't connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("universiteti", $con);
if(isset($_POST['uname'])){
    // write to the database inside of here

$res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email,emri) VALUES('{$_POST['uname']}', '{$_POST['pwd']}', '{$_POST['email']}', '{$_POST['name']}')");

if(! $res) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(\Enter valid data ! \')</script>';
           }
 else {
$user_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='{$_POST['uname']}'");

$do_user_check = mysql_num_rows($user_check);


//Now if email is already in use


$email_check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='{$_POST['email']}'");

$do_email_check = mysql_num_rows($email_check);


//Now display errors


if($do_user_check > 1){

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(\'This username is already in use! \')</script>';

}

if($do_email_check > 1){

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(\'This email is already in use! \')</script>';
}       
}
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(\'Successfuly registrated! \')</script>';

}
?>
```

In your html form keep the variable name as uname, pwd, email

Comment: mysql_* is depricated. You are storing your passwords as plain text (bad practice).

Comment: thank you but what about registration? i think i am having problem with encryption af password. could you please give me the registration code

Comment: @aural varchar will be ok. and i updated it with registraton code.

Comment: what about encryption? or its not needed?

Comment: @aural encryption is needed for security. you needd to google regarding encrypting password then storing

Comment: thank you very much it works :) but i want an other thing to show me welcome username on the top of the page where i want to redirect after login, could you explain where to put this piece of code?

Comment: @aural you need to put this code in the page in which you are redirecting. in my program after sucessful login i am redirecting the user to index.php page so your "welcome user" piece of code must be in that file

Comment: please could you give me also the piece of code for successful login because it is not working !

Answer (score 0):

---

First of all you need to save only hash to determine if password was entered correctly don't save plain password in database. Also if you are using PDO use it anywere, i mean

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,hash,email) 
VALUES(:username,:hash,:email)");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':hash', $hash);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

Also strange that your hash is "*0" maybe you had set length of hash field to 2 in database?

---

Comment: Field --->hash
Type ---->  VARCHAR 
Length/Values1 ----> 100
Default2 NONE

Collation 
Attributes 
Null 
AUTO_INCREMENT 
Comments 
MIME type 
Browser transformation 
Transformation options3

Comment: i did what you told but i still get this: object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["hash"]=> string(2) "*0" } Login failed

Comment: Replace `$salt = sprintf('$2a$%02d$?', $cost) . $salt;` line, this is no needed and it breaks all passwords to *0